# how to access @RequestParam to get file name in spring rest controller

Tags: spring

I want to get the file name uploaded using this end point in another method

```
 @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
public UploadFileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile 
    file) {
    String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);

    String fileDownloadUri = 
       ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
            .path("/downloadFile/")
            .path(fileName)
            .toUriString();

    return new UploadFileResponse(UUID.randomUUID(), fileName, fileDownloadUri, file.getContentType(), file.getSize());
}
```

the other method is to send file name along with some data into mongodb.

```
    @PostMapping("/uploadPath")
 public String setPath(@RequestBody Image image ) {
     image.setImageId(UUID.randomUUID());
     String fileName = m.
     image.setFileName(fileName);
     String filePath = Paths.get(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir()).toAbsolutePath().normalize()+File.separator+fileName; 
     image.setImagePath(filePath);
      imgserv.insertPath(image);

 }
```

Is it possible to access filename from endppoint(/uploadFile) and store in database using endpoint(/uploadPath)

Comment: umm is the filename actually sent? I didnt know that .

Comment: Any other way to store the file name into mongodb?